# How to convert string[] to int in C#

Tags: c#

I'm a begginer to C# programmer and I have a problem in my code with one string.
I want to know how I can convert this string:

```
x = {"1","2","0",",","1","2","1",",","1","2","2"}
```

into something like this:

```
x = {"120","121","122"}
```

The variable x is assigned as string and I want it assigned as int. The purpose of this is to get how many numbers are between lets say 120 and 130, which in my string would be 3.

Many Thanks.

Comment: In your example of what you're looking for, `x` is still an array. If you want it to be an `int`, it would have to be 120121122, or you would need 3 variables.

Comment: So you actually have a string that contains `x = {"1","2","0",",","1","2","1",",","1","2","2"}`? Or a string variable x which is `{"1","2","0",",","1","2","1",",","1","2","2"}`? Or do you have an array of strings?

Comment: bikeshedding in action....

Comment: I have a array of strings, sloth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] x = { "1", "2", "0", ",", "1", "2", "1", ",", "1", "2", "2" };
int[] y = string.Join(string.Empty, x)
                .Split(',')
                .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in three lines as follows:

```
var x = new []{"1", "2", "0", ",", "1", "2", "1", ",", "1", "2", "2"};
var fullString = String.Join("", x, 0, x.Length);

// get as a string array:
// x = fullString.Split(new[] {','});

// get as an integer array:
var intArray = (fullString.Split(new[] {','}))
                  .Select(_ => Int32.Parse(_)).ToArray();
```

In steps this is (1) create the string, (2) join the string, (3) split the string on the separator (which appears to be the comma in your case).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do this but never the less it can be achieved quite simply using <strike>LINQ to Objects</strike> basic `String` methods.

```
var x = new string[] { "1", "2", "0", ",", "1", "2", "1", ",", "1", "2", "2" };
var y = String.Join(String.Empty, x).Split(',');

foreach (var s in y)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

**Update 23/05/2014**

As per the comments, here is some code that will do what you want (i.e. count the numbers between the range 120-130 inclusive).

```
var min = 120;
var max = 130;

var count = y
    .Select(o => Int32.Parse(o))
    .Count(o => (min <= o) && (o <= max));

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: But you don't use LINQ to Objects in your answer, just basic string functions :-)

Comment: Haha good shout, where is my mind at..

Comment: Thanks mate, this helped me. However, how can I convert the value of s to a integer? I want to count how many numbers are between a range after this and I can't becouse the value os s is a string. Can you help me?

Comment: To convert a string to an integer you can use the static method `Int32.Parse(s)`,  I don't quite understand what you mean by *"count how many numbers are between a range"* though, could you explain a little more?

Comment: I want to find the total number between a range like this:

max = 130;
min = 120;

then in my example the total number is 3. 
That what I want :)

Comment: I want to find the total number between a range like this:

max = 130;
min = 120;

then in my example the total number is 3. 
That what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

You should first add the 3 strings together to get the correct "120","121","122" as a string
Then you could use a forloop or something equivalent to do val.toint();

EDIT:

Changing a list from list String  to Int and keeping the same variable seems abit unnecessary to me

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using several string methods and LINQ:

```
string[] x = { "1", "2", "0", ",", "1", "2", "1", ",", "1", "2", "2" };
string all = string.Join("", x); // "120,121,122"
string[] parts = all.Split(','); // { "120", "121", "122" }
int i = int.MinValue;            // variable which is used in below query
int[] y = parts                                // LINQ query
    .Where(s => int.TryParse(s.Trim(), out i)) // filters out invalid strings
    .Select(s => i)                            // selects the parsed ints
    .ToArray();                                // creates the final array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] x = { "1", "2", "0", ",", "1", "2", "1", ",", "1", "2", "2" };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in x)
{
    sb.Append(item);
}

string str = sb.ToString();
string[] myArr = str.Split(',');

int[] numArr = new int[myArr.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++)
{
    numArr[i] = int.Parse(myArr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with a bit of effort, youll be able to find this,(you are not supposed to just post a question, next time do some research please) but whilst the question is here any way:

```
        string[] items;
        items = new string[5];
        int[] intitems;
        intitems = new int[5];

        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int.TryParse(items[i], out intitems[i]);
        }
```

an easy and understandable way of doing it. the loop pretty much explains it self